# Library for traversing object property tree on C#

Tags: c#

I want to have a method that could traverse an object by property names and get me the value of the property.

More specifically as an input I have a string like "Model.Child.Name" and I want this method to take an object and get me the value that could be found programatically via: object.Model.Child.Name.

I understand that the only way to do this is to use Reflection, but I don't want to write this code on my own, because I believe that there are pitfalls. Moreover, I think it is more or less usual task.

Is there any well-known implementation of algorithm like that on C#?

Comment: Reflection IS the way btw, but if you are set against that you've got an option to use serialization (into JSON or XML) and then access the output nodes by string key values.

Comment: This should get you started : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14560/Fast-Dynamic-Property-Field-Accessors . It uses Reflection and Reflection.Emit to build accessors using string names and mitigate reflection's traditional performance issues. It does not support the dot notation, but you could easily implement it yourself using this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the way to go.

[Reflection to access properties at runtime](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/applied-reflection-dynamically-accessing-properties-of-a-class-at-runtime/6099345)

You can take a look at [ObjectDumper](http://objectdumper.codeplex.com/) and modify the source code as per your requirement.

ObjectDumper take a .NET object and dump it to string, file, textWriter etc.

Answer (score 1):

The is not that difficult to write. Yes there are some pitfalls, but it's good to know the pitfalls.

The algorithm is straightforward, it's traversing a tree structure. At each node you inspect it for a primitive value (int, string, char, etc) if it's not one of these times, then its a structure that has one or more primitives and needs to be traversed to it's primitives.

The pitfalls are dealing with nulls, nullable types, value versus reference types, etc. Straight forward stuff that every developer should know about.